# How to set right path imports in VSCode?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I have a root app directory with the following folders:

```
/app/
/environments/
```

Inside `/app/` exist `helpers/Helper.ts`:

```
/app/helper/Helper.ts
```

In this file I tried to import environments:

```
import { environment } from "../../environments/environment.prod";
```

Two directories back, it is right, it works.

Problem is when compiler compiles code it says:

> Error: com.tns.NativeScriptException: Failed to find module:
>   "../../environments/environment.prod", relative to: app/helpers/

So, my **tsconfig** contains:

```
   { "baseUrl": "./" }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

usually it does work well.

What I suggest is to use "paths" in your tsconfig

```
"paths": {
      "@env": [
        "environments/*"
      ],
    }
```

in your code

```
import { environment } from "@env/environment.prod";
```

Comment: Do you have the plugin set from john papa for angular installed? Try to restart VSCode it does work for me with VSCode, I am getting also code suggestions.

Comment: Yes, I have installed such plugin

Comment: Also I have relaunched, the same result

Comment: When I did autoimport it import this: `import { environment } from "@env";`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47700939/how-to-reset-intellisense-in-vs-code

Comment: @OPV try to restart TS server

Comment: Each time I do this, no result

Comment: @OPV sry but no more ideas... might be a local problem