# C++ IntelliSense in Visual Studio Code doesnt recognize C++ STL

Tags: c++, gcc, visual-studio-code, clang, intellisense

I'm using Visual Studio Code on my Linux laptop.
I just wrote a simple program like this one in `main.cpp`:

```cpp
#include<iostream>

int main()
{

}
```

Yesterday everything was working just fine. Today I open a new file and it says it doesnt recognize any of STL libraries. This is what I get when I hover over it:

```
#include errors detected. Please update your includePath. Squiggles are disabled for this translation unit (/home/john/Documents/main.cpp).C/C++(1696)
cannot open source file "iostream"C/C++(1696)
```

I run a few command to check my compiler and setting. Those are my intellisense settings:

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Linux",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**"
            ],
            "defines": [],
            "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/clang",
            "cStandard": "c11",
            "cppStandard": "c++17",
            "configurationProvider": "go2sh.cmake-integration"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

This is some info about my `g++` compiler and my `clang` compiler:

`g++`

```
john@john-GL63-8RC:~$ whereis g++
g++: /usr/bin/g++ /usr/share/man/man1/g++.1.gz
john@john-GL63-8RC:~$ g++ --version
g++ (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1) 7.4.0
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

`clang`:

```
john@john-GL63-8RC:~$ whereis clang
clang: /usr/bin/clang /usr/lib/clang /usr/include/clang /usr/share/man/man1/clang.1.gz
john@john-GL63-8RC:~$ clang --version
clang version 6.0.0-1ubuntu2 (tags/RELEASE_600/final)
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /usr/bin
```

Also I think they are old but all I did was to install the via apt-get how do I update them?
How can I repair it? I didnt change anything and it just started going crazy by itself

Comment: What about https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18289936/refreshing-the-auto-complete-intellisense-database-in-visual-studio or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47700939/how-to-reset-intellisense-in-vs-code

Comment: I just looked up my /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/ and there are no header files!
How did it happen?
Like if iostream and other files evaporated

Comment: I don't see how they could disappear.  You're only option is to reinstall the compiler I think.

Comment: I did reinstall it and the files are now there. iostream, vector etc are there. And the proper directory is given. But it still doesn't see them! I mean the intellisense
How can this be possible?