# Could not find a declaration file for module 'vue-html-to-paper'

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am trying to get a sample project working with HTML to PDF but I keep getting an error saying.

```
Could not find a declaration file for module 'vue-html-to-paper'
```

However, it is in my `node_modules`

index.js

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter, { RouteConfig } from 'vue-router'
import VueHtmlToPaper from 'vue-html-to-paper';

Vue.use(VueHtmlToPaper);
Vue.use(VueRouter)
```

component

```html
<template>
<div>
    <div>
        <h2>I am a H2 tag</h2>
    </div>
     <!-- SOURCE -->
    <div id="printMe">
      <h1>Print me!</h1>
      <div>&#x25A0; &#x25A0; &#x25A0; &#x25A0; &#x25A0; &#x25A0;</div>
    </div>
    <!-- OUTPUT -->
    <!-- https://printjs.crabbly.com/ -->
    <button @click="print">Click to print!</button>

</div>

</template>

<script lang="ts">
import Vue from 'vue';
import VueHtmlToPaper from 'vue-html-to-paper';

export default class TestComponent extends Vue {

  print () {
      // Pass the element id here
      this.$htmlToPaper('printMe');
    }

}
</script>
```

[image]

I have deleted the node_modules a few times to no avail. Has anyone run into this issue before with this package?

package.json file

```js
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "docx": "^5.4.1",
    "vue": "^2.6.11",
    "vue-html-to-paper": "^1.3.1", <---- here
    "vue-router": "^3.2.0",
    "vuex": "^3.4.0"
  },
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure the package is installed (aka: can you post your package.json)? It seems your editor is giving some kind of warning/error by underlining the package name which might suggest something is off there.

Secondly: if you already import the package and register it with Vue in index.js, there is no need of importing it again in the component.

Comment: what is the warning on the import `vue-html-to-paper` in the screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

The `vue-html-to-paper` package doesn't have any type declaration files (`*.d.ts`), so your app will have to [declare the module](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50516783/6277151) itself. That is, to resolve the `Could not find a declaration file` error, declare the `vue-html-to-paper` module by adding the folowing line to `src/shims-vue.d.ts`:

```js
declare module 'vue-html-to-paper';
```

To [augment the Vue prototype](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/typescript.html#Augmenting-Types-for-Use-with-Plugins) with the plugin's [`$htmlToPaper()` method](https://github.com/mycurelabs/vue-html-to-paper/blob/8904269/src/index.js#L13),  create `src/vue-html-to-paper.d.ts` with these contents:

```js
import Vue from 'vue';

interface HtmlToPaperOptions {
  name: string;
  specs: string[];
  replace: boolean;
  styles: string[];
}

declare module 'vue/types/vue' {
  interface Vue {
    $htmlToPaper: (el: Element, localOptions?: Partial<HtmlToPaperOptions>, cb?: () => boolean) => void;
  }
}

export {}
```

...and then [restart VS Code's TypeScript Language Service](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55212141/6277151) (or just restart the IDE itself) to load the new type declarations file.