# VSCODE not recognizing angular, errors everywhere even if it compiles successfully

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio-code, npm

I'm trying to load an angular project in vscode, I used to work on this project with no problem, but suddenly vscode started showing errors everywhere in the project. I already have angular installed and all the required extensions for it.

[image]

I tried to resolve the problem with `npm cache clean`, `npm ci`, and also tried to uninstall @angular/cli but nothing worked for me, the problem still persist.

The project is compiling and running successfully but the errors don't disappear and I can't get ride of them.

Comment: It sounds like it might be an intellisense issue - an answer may be in this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47700939/how-to-reset-intellisense-in-vs-code#:~:text=You%20may%20Ctrl%2BShift%2BP,%2FC%2B%2B%20Reset%20IntelliSense%20database%22.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why, but I could resolve this issue by uninstalling vscode and installing it again, but in case you have the same problem, please look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47700939/how-to-reset-intellisense-in-vs-code#:%7E:text=You%20may%20Ctrl%2BShift%2BP,%2FC%2B%2B%20Reset%20IntelliSense%20database%22) before applying mine.

**Edited! :**
After a while the errors appeared again, so after some researches I found the problem was because of Eslint extension that was not configured with Typescript correctly, so to fix the error I added the command bellow and magically all the errors disappeared:

```
npm install --save-dev eslint @typescript-eslint/parser @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin
```

More info about how to configure Eslint with Typescript [here](https://khalilstemmler.com/blogs/typescript/eslint-for-typescript/).